# Ajax API calls in loop need to be executed in order

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics-api, jquery-deferred

lets say you have a scenario where you needed to create a .csv output in a page's textarea...

So I have an array of queries which i loop. Inside the loop im passing a query to an ajax call... I need to append the result of the ajax call into the textarea.

My question is how do you get the results printed out in the order they are requested (basically the order in the queries array)

```
//example array to loop.
var queries= ['query1', 'query', 'query3', 'query4'];

//the textarea where im going to print the results in order later to open in excel as a .csv file
var $csvText= $('#some-text-area');

//inserting the csv headers
$csvText.val('Column1, Column2\r\n');

$.each(queries, function(index, value){
   //someGoogleAPI is an ajax call from google's api
   someGoogleAPI(value).then(function(response){
      //Adding row with values
      $csvText.val(response.column1 + ',' response.column2 + '\r\n');
   });
})
```

This is simplified example but by resolving this I would get an idea of how to tackle my problem.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your queries do not depend upon each other and thus can be executed in parallel.  If that's the case, then you really just need to get the responses processed in order.  You can do that several ways:

**Run in Parallel with Promise.all()**

Launch all the requests in parallel, collect all the results, use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done and then insert all the results.

```
//example array to loop.
var queries= ['query1', 'query', 'query3', 'query4'];

//the textarea where im going to print the results in order later to open in excel as a .csv file
var $csvText= $('#some-text-area');

//inserting the csv headers
$csvText.val('Column1, Column2\r\n');

Promise.all(queries.map(function(item) {
   return someGoogleAPI(value);
})).then(function(results) {
   $csvText.append(results.map(function(item) {
        return response.column1 + ',' response.column2;
   }).join('\r\n'));       
});
```

`Promise.all()` will collect the results in order, regardless of which requests actually finished first.

**Sequence Your Operations**

You can sequence your operations so only one is run at a time, it's result is inserted, then the next one is run and so on.  This will be a slower end-to-end run time, but gives you intermediate display of results.

```
//example array to loop.
var queries= ['query1', 'query', 'query3', 'query4'];

//the textarea where im going to print the results in order later to open in excel as a .csv file
var $csvText= $('#some-text-area');

//inserting the csv headers
$csvText.val('Column1, Column2\r\n');

queries.reduce(function(p, item) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return someGoogleAPI(item).then(function(result) {
            $csvText.append(result.column1 + ',' result.column2 + '\r\n');
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

This will create a series of chained promises that will execute in order, one after the other which each one inserting its result when it arrives.

Comment: Thanks :) , Just tried the first example you made and its not running in order check out http://jsfiddle.net/Egli/pq3cj8nx/6/ checking out the second one now..

Comment: Just tried the second example http://jsfiddle.net/Egli/ordh2nLk/ and again they dont run in order hmmm...

Comment: @EgliBecerra - They look to me like they run in order in your jsFiddle.  What do you think is not in order?

Comment: the results of jsfiddle.net/Egli/ordh2nLk

`Object {column1: "query3 column1", column2: "query3 column2"}
VM170:61Object {column1: "query4 column1", column2: "query4 column2"}
VM170:61 Object {column1: "query1 column1", column2: "query1 column2"}
VM170:61 Object {column1: "query column1", column2: "query column2"}
VM170:61 Object {column1: "query3 column1", column2: "query3 column2"}
VM170:61 Object {column1: "query4 column1", column2: "query4 column2"}`

Note the order by looking at **query<number>**

Comment: mate updated the fiddle to simulate the randomness of the ajax call should be better seen now http://jsfiddle.net/Egli/ordh2nLk/ check the console...

Comment: @Egil - I get this result `{"column1":"query1 column1","column2":"query1 column2"}, 
{"column1":"query column1","column2":"query column2"}
, {"column1":"query3 column1","column2":"query3 column2"}
, {"column1":"query4 column1","column2":"query4 column2"}` which looks properly ordered.

Comment: @EgliBecerra - I don't know.  You keep changing it while I'm looking at it.  Who knows what version I'm looking at.

Comment: @EgliBecerra - The one I just looked at has a syntax error in it and won't run.

Comment: @EgliBecerra - It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ordh2nLk/15/.  All I did from your last version was fix the syntax errors and put the output into the textarea so it's easier to see.

Comment: @EgliBecerra - That is the order of your queries array and is what I would expect.  What do you think is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $.each you can use reduce to create an arbitrary list of promises.

```
queries.reduce(function(seq, val) {
    return seq.then(function() {
      return someGoogleAPI(val)
    })
    .then(function(response){
        var curr = $csvText.val();
        $csvText.val(curr + ',' + response.column1 + ',' + response.column2 + '\r\n');
      });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75sse6n2/

Comment: Nice approach i can get it to work like this, your fiddle prints out the results  randomly sometimes... the order of the prints is important... thank heaps anyways i like the code.